# Function Pointer basic question

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a basic question on function pointer.
In the below code snippet, how do I read this "
`*(FARPROC*)&pfn =`"?

```
IFastString *CallCreateFastString(const char *psz) {

static IFastString * (*pfn)(const char *) = 0;

if (!pfn) {

const TCHAR szDll[] = _TEXT("FastString.DLL");

const char szFn[] = "CreateFastString";

HINSTANCE h = LoadLibrary(szDll);

if (h)

*(FARPROC*)&pfn = GetProcAddress(h, szFn);

}

return pfn ? pfn(psz) : 0;

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `GetProcAddress`- you'll see that the case above is convoluted...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really about function pointers, but about casting in general.

Suppose `pfn` is of type `T`. Then `&pfn` is of type `T*`. This gets cast to `FARPROC*` by the cast expression (the stuff in the parentheses). Finally, this gets dereferenced, yielding a `FARPROC&`.

All in all this just means you're treating `pfn` as if it were of type `FARPROC` and assign a value to it.

Here's a generic example:

```
S make_an_S();

T x;
T * const px = &x;
S * const py = (S*)px;
*py = make_an_S();  // same as *(S*)&x = make_an_S();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*(FARPROC*)&pfn = GetProcAddress(h, szFn);
```

is equivalent to,

```
(FARPROC)pfn = GetProcAddress(h, szFn);
```

So, `pfn` is a function pointer which is type casted to `FARPROC` to store the address received from `GetProcAddress(h, szFn)`.

[Note: I am not sure, if this kind of typecasting is deprecated in C++.]

Comment: It is not equivalent. You need a lvalue (eg. a reference type) in the left hand side, hence the indirection.

Comment: @Alexandre, couldn't get your point. Isn't `(FARPROC)pfn` an lvalue ?

Comment: no it isn't. When you write `(FARPROC)pfn`, you cast `pfn`'s value and it becomes a rvalue.

Comment: @Alexandre, if you are talking about strict aliasing rules, then may be you are right. However, I have seen such code in my old DSP project, which was written in `C`. That's why I mentioned about deprecation.

Comment: If you have `int x;` and then you do `(unsigned)x = 1` then this won't do the trick. You need `*(unsigned*)&x = 1` to do type punning. Here you have the same problem: you need the indirection to build a lvalue. Note that in C++ you'd use `static_cast` here instead.